# Derivative of the vector $\|y\|^2 \cdot x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be two vectors of $n$ components.

I want do derivate the expression $\|y\|^2x$ with respect to $y$. This should be a matrix. Now, I know that the derivative of $\|y\|^2$ is $2y$, so I know the result should be a proper product of $2y$ and $x$ that results in a matrix. But is the answer the matrix $2yx^T$ or $2xy^T$? How do I know which order is correct?

Comment: It does not matter. Both are the same, $2\sum_i x_iy_i$

Comment: It depends on your convention, it could be either (or even options which are neither). In (raised/lowered) index notation, if $x,y$ are both column vectors (i.e. upper indexed), then the answer is unambiguously $2xy^T$

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to specify, yep. They are column vectors.

Comment: @Andrei your notation suggests you either went a step too far or confused your indices and found the trace of the derivative instead of the derivative itself. Both options are transposes of each other so they would have the same trace, but they are not equivalent.

Comment: It all depends on how you've learned to calculate differentials
$$df=dy\cdot\nabla f \quad\iff\quad df = J\cdot dy
 \qquad \left(\,\nabla f = J^T\,\right)$$
The LHS uses the _gradient_ while the RHS uses the _Jacobian_,
but as you can see they are trivially related. In this particular problem
$J=2xy^T\:$